# Системные вызовы в python

Tags: python, g++, ос

Хочу скомпилировать код на `с++` и результат компиляции/работы вывести в консоль. Пытаюсь так вот делать:

```
import subprocess, os, sys
err = ''
err = subprocess.check_output(['g++', 'tst.cpp'], shell = True)

x = ''
if err == '':
    x = subprocess.check_output(["a.exe"], shell = True)
else:
    x = err

try:
    os.remove('a.exe')
except:
    pass

print x
```

При ошибке компияции выскакивает исключение `CalledProcessError: Command '['g++', 'tst.cpp']' returned non-zero exit status 1`. Мне надо, чтобы в x записывалась сама ошибка. Кажется, что кручусь вокруг да около, но не понимаю, в чем проблема

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> err = subprocess.check_output(['g++', 'tst.cpp'], shell = True)
> ```

Это не правильно. Вы должны либо передавать аргументы списком и забыть про экранирование аргументов:

```
err = subprocess.check_output(['g++', 'some file name!.cpp'])
```

Либо строкой с параметром `shell=True` и самим заботится об экранировании:

```
err = subprocess.check_output('g++ some\ file\ name\!.cpp', shell=True)
```

> хочу скомпилировать код на с++ и результат компиляции/работы вывести в консоль.

Если вам нужно что бы просто вывод шел в stdin и stderr, то просто вызывайте:

```
errcode = subprocess.call(['g++', 'tst.cpp'])
if errcode != 0:
    # произошла ошибка
```

Или обрабатывайте исключение:

```
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(['g++', 'tst.cpp'])
    # команда успешно выполнена
    # ...
    output = subprocess.check_output(["a.exe"])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as ex:
    # произошла ошибка
    err = ex.output
```

Comment: try:

    output = subprocess.check_output(['g++', 'tst.cpp'])
    output = subprocess.check_output(["a.exe"])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as ex:
    err = ex.output

Ничего не выводится при ошибке.

Comment: IMHO дело в том, что g++ пишет в stderr, а в e.output видимо д.б. stdout.

В sh stderr и stdout можно объединить

    g++ tst.cpp 2>&1

или объеденить и перенаправить в файл

    g++ tst.cpp >g++.results 2>&1

Наверное в питоне в классе subprocess должен быть метод, позволяющий делать аналогичные опнрации.

Comment: @Иванушка, вы `print(err)` добавляли? Я не стал это в листинг добавлять, т.к. решил, что это итак очевидно.

@avp, я сначала тоже так предположил, но просто тест

    >>> from subprocess import check_output, CalledProcessError
    >>> try: check_output('echo normal output; echo error output >&2; false', shell=True)
    ... except CalledProcessError as ex: print(ex.output)
    ... 
    error output
    normal output

показал, что туда и stderr, и stdout попадают.

Comment: да, очевидно, я так и сделал)) хоть и для меня эти потоки пока "темный лес". спасибо за помощь =)